# NHibernate one-to-many entity mapping - does the key column need to be nullable?

Tags: java, .net, hibernate, nhibernate

In the book Java Persistence with Hibernate under the section titled "Many Valued Associations" there is an example where a parent object  (Item) contains a list of associated entity objects (Bid). The example is on page 290 in my edition.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.shane.Hibernate1.Item" table="Item">
    <id name="ItemId" column="ItemId">
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>

    <property name="Synopsis" column="Synopsis"/>

    <list name="bids" cascade="save-update">
      <key column ="ItemId" not-null="true"/>
      <list-index column="Sequence"/>
      <one-to-many class="com.shane.Hibernate1.Bid"/>
    </list>    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>  

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.shane.Hibernate1.Bid" table="Bid">
    <id name="BidId" column="BidId">
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>    
    <property name="synopsis" column="Synopsis"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I tried the following with NHibernate both 2.1.2.GA and 3.1.0.GA:

```
 Item item = new Item();
 item.setSynopsis("Item 1");

 Bid bid = new Bid();
 bid.setSynopsis("Bid1");     
 item.getBids().add(bid);

 session.save(item);
```

NHibernate first inserts a new row in Item first then trys to insert an row into Bid but fails as it does not include the ItemId and Sequence columns if the table has these columns set to not null. If I make these columns nullable it works because it then does an update on Bid to set them but I don't want them to be nullable.

I tried this using Hibernate 3.1.rc2 and it works - when it does the insert it supplies all the values but strangely it still does an update on ItemId and Sequence on the Bid table afterwards.

Is this a bug in NHibernate? I would expect this kind fo behaviour to be the same for both of java and .Net versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NHibernate, you need a bidirectional relationship if you need not-null foreign keys in collections. Read the note a the end of http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-onetomany

This is certainly one of the most requested changes to NH, which doesn't necessarily match Hibernate 100% of the time; it's just based on it.

---

Update: this restriction unfortunately makes it effectively impossible to do it with a `list`.

The workaround is using a `bag` or `set` instead, and mapping the index as a regular property.

Comment: I read the note you mentioned and if I understand corrently if says that my collection mapping needs to be the inverse end of a biderectonal relationship to avoid a nullable FK column. However that won't work in this case as I want a list. It can't be mapped as inverse as the one-to-many end doesn't know what value the index column needs to be set to. So it looks like having nullable FK and index columns is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

I seems solution like this...

Bid bid = new Bid();
session.save(bid);

Item item = new Item();
item.getBids().add(new Bid(bid.getBidId()));
session.save(item).

where In BID() class should have one Parameterized constructor.

I hope it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

I think the Item clas should have many to one reference. So you should save Item. Then set reference in bid (bit.setItem(item)) and save the bid.

Comment: Bid can have a many-to-one mapping to make the mapping bi-directional but as mentioned in the book it must have update="false" and insert="false" to simulate making it the inverse end of the relationship. However this is just a convinience as for a list mapping the parant has to do the update as only it knows the value of the index column. After futher experimentation I found that (bizarely) I can make it work on java by setting casacade="save-update" on the list mapping but it still doesn't work on NHibernate. Will modify my question accordingly.